# Setting a streaming values to React state

Tags: reactjs, rethinkdb

Currently I have an sample app where I try to use RethinkDB with React.

In RethinkDB they have [**changefeed**](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/changes/) which listens for changes (insert, update, deleted) in the subscribed table.

When "feed" socket event is called it will append the newly created record to the state. When performing update I want to modify the current state users but when I try to log the values, it still empty array but I want to modify a specific record based on the id return by socket event response.

Example:

Suppose the current value of `users` state after `socket.emit('load')` call:

```
{id: "0e6dde2c-b21b-4963-9a06-393b04dfeb45", name: "updaste."} App.js:28 
{id: "106682b4-1395-4f8a-9758-5dd1d73b4174", name: "test1xx"} App.js:28 
{id: "60b7c8cf-b40f-4209-a7ef-ff51735ae7c5", name: "William Adama", posts: Array(3), tv_show: "Battlestar Galactica"} App.js:28 
{id: "ff920ad9-fc1d-4034-a7e8-d96b502935d3", name: "tesst"} App.js:28
```

Now in the backend I updated the record:  ff920ad9-fc1d-4034-a7e8-d96b502935d3, `socket.on('feed')` will return

```
{id: "ff920ad9-fc1d-4034-a7e8-d96b502935d3", name: "updated"}
```

I want to update the array element in `users` state so I did this.

```
ws.on("feed", response => {
      console.log(response);
      const prevUser = [...users]
      let result = prevUser.find(t => t.id === response.id) 
      if (result) {
        result.name = response.name
      }
      setUsers(user => [...user, response]);
});
```

it returns `[]` for `users` and `undefined` for `result`. I did not bother appending the `result` to setUsers since it is undefined anyway.

**Complete snippet:**

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  ws.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected");
    ws.emit("load"); // server will emit the "feed" message
    console.log(`emitted`);
  });

  // will be called when "load" message was emitted
  ws.on("feed", response => {
    console.log(response);
    const prevUser = [...users];
    let result = prevUser.find(t => t.id === response.id);
    if (result) {
      result.name = response.name;
    }
    console.log(result);

    setUsers(user => [...user, response]);
  });
});
```

The `response` object is streaming value.

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: What does `response` object return? [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` if nothing is found in the array given the predicate.

Comment: response returns this: {id: "ff920ad9-fc1d-4034-a7e8-d96b502935d3", name: "updated"}
when using Array.find since the users array is empty it will always return undefined.

Comment: So, initially, users array is empty. Then, you add a response to the array. If another value comes from the stream, you will see that users array is not empty. Shouldn’t it how it should be working? To be honest, I don’t understand what the issue is.

Comment: Okay, so my problem is the users array has been populated after the first socket event emit but when I try to inspect its value, it says [] so probably that's why Array.find does not work.

Comment: Can you create an effect that is dependent on `users` and print the contents? Also, this effect will start over every time there is a rerender because there are no deps. Can you move the `prevUser.find` code inside the state updater function?

Comment: tried both but still the users state array is empty.

Comment: Sorry, can’t help you more than this. This should have worked. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. For example, currently you are opening a new socket for every new render. But still, that shouldn’t have caused the array to be empty.

Comment: @Gasim I tried again the functional version of setState and it works perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yeah, my guess is the following: either you have stale state value (do you set empty array as you dependency?) or the messages come too fast, which fails to update the state in time. Functional updates ensure that previous value in during the update is the latest value.

Comment: I think I have stale state value since I set empty array as dependency.

Comment: That makes sense then. It wasn't there in the snippet that you provided; that why, it was hard to diagnose.